# How should I be doing LAN name resolution on 18.04

Tags: networking, dns, systemd-resolved

How should I be doing LAN enable name resolution on 18.04?

I have a LAN full of Ubuntu 16.04 devices, connected via a router running dnsmasq. All the local devices have a single word names, IP are not fixed, and are resolved via dnsmasq (as it also handles DHCP). I have upgraded my laptop to 18.04, and it's DNS requests are being blocked by systemd resolved for some reason.

I'd like to know, what is the most sensible long term strategy to minimise admin burden.

1. When I upgrade everything to 18.04 systemd resolved will work using some LAN discovered protocol.
2. Reconfigure systemd resolved to use DNS for single word names.
3. There's a proper naming strategy I should be using.
4. Suck it up, and hard code all the device IP addresses on all the other devices.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 17.10 they changed to netplan to manage networks.

for desktop it is now netplan/networkmanager
for server (headerless) it is now netplan/networkd

So basically anything you have edited in the past doesn't really work anymore. To make life more confusing it is all still there, and editing it can just add further layers of problem (that's experience talking). Once I just started working with only the netplan stuff, everything started to work again.

As far as I understand you now edit gui from within the gui (I don't use the gui), if you google ubuntu 18.04 static ip netplan networkd you will probably find what you are looking for. I have only just discovered most of this, and I am still not 100% sure how it all works, which is why I have not told you how I setup my network stuff. Bad advise only makes things worse.

My key info was found here: https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-static-ip-addresses-on-ubuntu-18-04-beta/

I hope this give you some clues. It's not that well documented that I can see.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Alas even setting up a fixed netplan, the name resolution isn't working. `nslookup server1` fails, whereas `nslookup server -ns 192.168.1.1` (where 192.168.1.1 is my local dnsmasq) works fine. The GUI network manager and ifconfig all confirm that `192.168.1.1` is my local DNS. I'm getting tired of manually configuring `hosts` keeping up with IP changes.